# how to access a json file(test data like config.json) in conftest.py

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Suppose in this example, how to access the respective `config.json` file in `conftest` fixtures upon executing test-suite using `pytest`.

```
$ pwd
/home/user/repo/main
$ pytest  testcases/project_(1/2)/test_suite_(1/2).py
```

Directory structure:

```
├── main
│  ├── conftest.py  # conftest file for my fixtures
│  ├── testcases     
│     ├── project_1
│     │   (contains these files --  test_suite_1.py, config.json)
│     └── project_2
│         (contains these files -- test_suite_2.py, config.json)
├── workflows
│  └── libs
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the path of the currently executed module via `request.node.fspath` and build the path to the `config.json` relative to it. `request` is a fixture provided by `pytest`. Here's an example based on the directory structure you provided.

```python
# main/conftest.py
import json
import pathlib
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def read_config(request):
    file = pathlib.Path(request.node.fspath)
    print('current test file:', file)
    config = file.with_name('config.json')
    print('current config file:', config)
    with config.open() as fp:
        contents = json.load(fp)
    print('config contents:', contents)
```

If you copy the code above to your `conftest.py` and run the tests with `-s`, you should get an output similar to this:

```
$ pytest -sv
=============================== test session starts ===============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.4.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /data/gentoo64/usr/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /data/gentoo64/tmp/so-50329629, inifile:
collected 2 items

main/project1/test_one.py::test_spam
current file: /data/gentoo64/tmp/so-50329629/main/project1/test_one.py
current config: /data/gentoo64/tmp/so-50329629/main/project1/config.json
config contents: {'name': 'spam'}
PASSED
main/project2/test_two.py::test_eggs
current file: /data/gentoo64/tmp/so-50329629/main/project2/test_two.py
current config: /data/gentoo64/tmp/so-50329629/main/project2/config.json
config contents: {'name': 'eggs'}
PASSED

============================= 2 passed in 0.08 seconds ============================
```

---

#### Use parsed config values

You can access the parsed JSON data by returning it in the fixture and using the fixture as one of the test arguments. I slightly modified the fixture from above so it returns the parsed data and removed the `autouse=True`:

```
@pytest.fixture
def json_config(request):
    file = pathlib.Path(request.node.fspath.strpath)
    config = file.with_name('config.json')
    with config.open() as fp:
        return json.load(fp)
```

Now simply use the fixture name in the test arguments, the value will be what the fixture returns. for example:

```
def test_config_has_foo_set_to_bar(json_config):
    assert json_config['foo'] == 'bar'
```

Comment: Thanks Hoefling, this worked for me with slightest change `request.node.fspath.strpath`. and also wanted to know how i can access this json data in test case or in test suite.

Comment: Hi @SunilKumar, check out the updated answer with an example for accessing the config values. As for `strpath` - I guess you're using a Python version older than 3.6, then yes, you need to convert `fspath` to string first - either use `fspath.strpath` or `str(request.fspath)`.

Comment: Hi @Hoefling, does the fixture here lies in conftest.py? and i just needed a way to access the data in test_class/test_cases in a test suite file which is in project directory.

Comment: You can place the fixture in conftest file or in the test file, it will work either way.

Comment: Glad I could help you! If you find the answer useful, you can accept it to mark the question as solved, or upvote it, or both.

Comment: Hi @Hoefling, is there a way to parametrize tests in above test environment, in case if different test data list is available for a single test?

Comment: Not quite clear what you mean - would be better if you open another question, providing [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But if you want to use the `pytest.mark.parametrize` with passing `json_config` fixture as an input, this won't work. However, as I see it, you don't need that fixture anyway and can read the configs once on module level. The read values you can then pass to parametrization marks.

Comment: Hi @Hoefling, created [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815777/parametrize-the-test-based-on-the-list-test-data-from-a-json-file)