# Parametrize the test based on the list test-data from a json file

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, pytest

Is there a way to parametrize a test, when test has a list of different/multiple test-data?

#### example_test_data.json

```
{ "test_one" : [1,2,3], # this is the case, where the `test_one` test need to be parametrize.
  "test_two" : "split",
  "test_three" : {"three":3},
  "test_four" : {"four":4},
  "test_set_comparison" : "1234"
}
```

## Directory structure:

- main --

  - conftest.py   # conftest file for my fixtures
  - testcases

    - project_1
      (contains these files --  test_suite_1.py, config.json)
    - project_2
      (contains these files -- test_suite_2.py, config.json)
  - workflows

    - libs

Using below code in conftest.py at top directory level, able to get/map the test data from json file for particular test case.

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def test_config(request):
  f = pathlib.Path(request.node.fspath.strpath)
  print "File : %s" % f
  config = f.with_name("config.json")
  print "Config json file : %s" % config
  with config.open() as fd:
    testdata = json.loads(fd.read())
  print "test data :", testdata
  yield testdata


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def config_data(request, test_config):
  testdata = test_config
  test = request.function.__name__
  print "Class Name : %s" % request.cls.__name__
  print "Testcase Name : %s" % test
  if test in testdata:
    test_args = testdata[test]
    yield test_args
  else:
    yield {}
```

In my case:

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def config_data(request, test_config):
  testdata = test_config
  test = request.function.__name__
  print "Class Name : %s" % request.cls.__name__
  print "Testcase Name : %s" % test
  if test in testdata:
    test_args = testdata[test]
    if isinstance(test_args, list):
       # How to parametrize the test 
       # yield test_args
  else:
    yield {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would handle the special parametrization case in `pytest_generate_tests` hook:

```
# conftest.py
import json
import pathlib
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def test_config(request):
    f = pathlib.Path(request.node.fspath.strpath)
    config = f.with_name("config.json")
    with config.open() as fd:
        testdata = json.loads(fd.read())
    yield testdata


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def config_data(request, test_config):
    testdata = test_config
    test = request.function.__name__
    if test in testdata:
        test_args = testdata[test]
        yield test_args
    else:
        yield {}


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'config_data' not in metafunc.fixturenames:
        return
    config = pathlib.Path(metafunc.module.__file__).with_name('config.json')
    testdata = json.loads(config.read_text())
    param = testdata.get(metafunc.function.__name__, None)
    if isinstance(param, list):
        metafunc.parametrize('config_data', param)
```

Some notes: [`yield_fixture` is deprecated](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/yieldfixture.html) so I replaced it with plain `fixture`. Also, you don't need `autouse=True` in fixtures that return values - you call them anyway.

Example tests and configs I used:

```
# testcases/project_1/config.json
{
    "test_one": [1, 2, 3],
    "test_two": "split"
}

# testcases/project_1/test_suite_1.py
def test_one(config_data):
    assert config_data >= 0

def test_two(config_data):
    assert config_data == 'split'


# testcases/project_2/config.json
{
    "test_three": {"three": 3},
    "test_four": {"four": 4}
}

# testcases/project_2/test_suite_2.py
def test_three(config_data):
    assert config_data['three'] == 3

def test_four(config_data):
    assert config_data['four'] == 4
```

Running the tests yields:

```
$ pytest -vs
============================== test session starts ================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.4.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0 --
/data/gentoo64/usr/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /data/gentoo64/home/u0_a82/projects/stackoverflow/so-50815777, inifile:
plugins: mock-1.6.3, cov-2.5.1
collected 6 items

testcases/project_1/test_suite_1.py::test_one[1] PASSED
testcases/project_1/test_suite_1.py::test_one[2] PASSED
testcases/project_1/test_suite_1.py::test_one[3] PASSED
testcases/project_1/test_suite_1.py::test_two PASSED
testcases/project_2/test_suite_2.py::test_three PASSED
testcases/project_2/test_suite_2.py::test_four PASSED

============================ 6 passed in 0.12 seconds =============================
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not much information available on it. There are some [apidocs on Metafunc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#metafunc) available, but they are rather technical; as for examples, take a look at [the official example in `pytest` docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example), also there are more examples of it here: [Parametrizing tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html).